# EF Code First Composite Key Relation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I was trying to create composite keys as well as a foreign key in License table with the customer but when I run the `EF` command `update-database`, the following columns are being generated in License table.

[image]

I have the following tables

```
public class Company
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}


 public class Customer
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public int CompanyId { get; set; }
     public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

     public ICollection<License> Licenses{ get; set; }
  }


public class License
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Count { get; set; }

   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}


public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("TestConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

    public DbSet<License> License { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(cust => new { cust.Id, cust.CompanyId })
            .Property(cust => cust.Id).HasColumnOrder(1)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(cust => cust.CompanyId).HasColumnOrder(2);



        modelBuilder.Entity<License>()
           .HasKey(lic => new { lic.Id, lic.CustomerId })
           .Property(lic => lic.Id).HasColumnOrder(1)
           .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<License>()
            .Property(lic => lic.CustomerId).HasColumnOrder(2);



        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Note**: I was expecting to have CustomerId act as PK and FK in License table, but don't know how those extra columns named `Customer_Id` and Customer_CompanyId` get's generated.

Comment: @mosh can yo help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.  Customer has a compound key, so you need two FK properties on License.  And you need to associate License.Customer with Customer.Licenses, otherwise it could be two separate associations.

Also you *should* put the parent keys first in the PK index for child entities.  That way related rows are stored together, and the PK index also supports the Foreign Key relationship.  Otherwise you really need two separate indexes:  Eg on Customer(Id) and on Customer(CompanyId).  If you want to be able to look up a customer on Id without company, then add an index on Customer(id).

Also EF will derive the Key column order from the anonymous type expression you use to declare the key, so you don't need to explicitly set it.

So like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ef62test
{
    class Program
    {

        public class Company
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
        public class Customer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int CompanyId { get; set; }
            public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

            public ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
        }


        public class License
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Count { get; set; }

            public int CompanyId { get; set; }
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }
            public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        }


        public class MyDbContext : DbContext
        {

            public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }

            public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

            public DbSet<License> License { get; set; }


            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                    .HasKey(cust => new { cust.CompanyId, cust.Id })
                    .Property(cust => cust.Id)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);


                modelBuilder.Entity<License>()
                   .HasKey(lic => new { lic.CompanyId, lic.CustomerId, lic.Id })
                   .Property(lic => lic.Id)
                   .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

                modelBuilder.Entity<License>()
                    .HasRequired(l => l.Customer)
                    .WithMany(c => c.Licenses)
                    .HasForeignKey(l => new { l.CompanyId, l.CustomerId });

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());

            using (var db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                db.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);

                db.Database.Initialize(true);



                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```